# JSF inputSwitch with confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a inputSwitch that need to show a dialog to confirm or not the operation. The dialog should show a variable message if i put it on or off.
I do the next thing but the problem is when i push no and i toggle the switch to let in then original state it call the ajax event again and open the dialog again. How can i lauch the event only when i click and not when i call the .toggle function?

```
                <p:outputLabel for="activa"
                    value="#{bundleBean.getValue('activa')}" />
                <p:inputSwitch id="activa"
                    value="#{gestionBean.domainEntity.activa}" onLabel="Si"
                    offLabel="No"
                    widgetVar="switch#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="test" oncomplete="PF('dialog#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}').show()"></p:ajax>
                </p:inputSwitch>

                <div>
                    <p:confirmDialog id="test" 
                        widgetVar="dialog#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}"
                        styleClass="content-confirmation-dialog"
                        message="#{gestionBean.mensajeDialogoActiva(gestionBean.domainEntity.activa)}"
                        header="#{bundleBean.getValue('confirmacion')}" closable="false">

                        <p:commandButton value="Si"
                            styleClass="boton rounded-button ui-button-danger float-right ui-confirmdialog-yes" immediate="true"
                            onclick="PF('dialog#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}').hide()" />
                        <!-- action="#{gestionBean.cambiarEstado(gestionBean.domainEntity)}"  -->
                        <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="boton rounded-button ui-button ui-confirmdialog-no"
                            immediate="true"
                            update="activa"
                            onclick="PF('switch#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}').toggle(); PF('dialog#{gestionBean.domainEntity.id}').hide()" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the **form**, instead of the **switch**, when you click the *No* button and the dialog will not be shown.

```
<p:commandButton update="@from">
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to solve this problem is to do away with the `p:confirmDialog` and instead have the change event on the `p:inputSwitch` / `p:toggleSwitch` trigger a click event on a hidden commandButton. For example:

```
            <p:inputSwitch id="toggle" value="#{toggleSwitchController.toggleOn}" >
                <p:ajax oncomplete="PF('hidnBtn').getJQ().click();"/>
            </p:inputSwitch>
            <p:commandButton id="hiddenBtn" widgetVar="hidnBtn" 
                             action="#{toggleSwitchController.toggleChanged}"
                             style="visibility: hidden;">
                <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update=":frm1:growl toggle"
                        listener="#{toggleSwitchController.handleReturn}" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

The action that the hidden `p:commandButton` calls can test the value of the toggle and if set to true/yes use PrimeFace's dialog framework to show a confirmation dialog. The dialog can return a boolean, which can be tested in the handleReturn function.

```
    public void toggleChanged() {
        if (toggleOn) {
            Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
            options.put("resizable", false);
            options.put("draggable", false);
            options.put("closable", false);
            options.put("modal", true);
            PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("/pages/pleaseConfirm", options, null);
        }
    }

    public void handleReturn(SelectEvent<Boolean> event) {
        boolean confirmed = event.getObject();
        if (confirmed) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "confirmed", null));
        } else {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "not confirmed", null));
            toggleOn = false;
        }
    }
```

You could make the "pleaseConfirm" dialog more reusable by providing parameters for the text strings through the openDynamic() call.

Comment: I don't know why but the ajax is not calling the click on when i change the switch. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: i got an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at install (blockUI.js.xhtml?ln=js&v=1_0:279)
    at Function.$.blockUI (blockUI.js.xhtml?ln=js&v=1_0:32)
    at bloquear (general.js.xhtml?ln=js&v=1_0:200)
    at showLoadingFeedback (general.js.xhtml?ln=js&v=1_0:189)

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using? I tested the code with PF v8.

Comment: Your JS error says "BlockUI" so I would look there.  Idon't see any BlockUI in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by adding a listener to the ajax change event, making the listener return the current value of the toggle and testing the returned value in the onComplete clause before showing the dialog.

```
            <p:inputSwitch id="activa"
                           value="#{toggleSwitchController.toggleOn}" 
                           onLabel="Si" offLabel="No"
                           widgetVar="toggleWidget" >
                <p:ajax event="change" 
                        listener="#{toggleSwitchController.testToggle}"
                        update="test" 
                        oncomplete="if ( args.toggleValue == 1 ) { PF('dlgWidget').show();}" />
            </p:inputSwitch>
```

The listener can be very simple:

```java
    public void testToggle() {
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("toggleValue", (toggleOn ? 1 : 0));
    }
```